# Parsing HTML using QWebElement, how to extract an image?

Tags: python, qt, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebelement

I struggle to use QWebElement. As an exercise, I would like to capture the "Google" logo from page http://www.google.com. The image is in `<div id="hplogo" ...>`, but I don't know how to extract it. How shall I use the "doc" QWebElement in the following code? ("CSS selector" is obscure jargon to me).
Thank you.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl

app = QApplication([])
view = QWebView()
view.load(QUrl("http://google.com"))
view.show()
doc = view.page().currentFrame().documentElement()   # run this after 'loadFinished'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the URL of the "Google" logo, do:

```
elem = doc.findFirst("div#hplogo")
qstring = elem.attribute('style')
regexp = QRegExp("^(.*:)?url\((.*)\)")
if regexp.indexIn(qstring) > -1:
    imageURL = regexp.capturedTexts()[-1]
```

It returns `imageURL = "/images/srpr/logo1w.png"`. It's necessary to use a regexp in that case because the URL is a part of a string. To get the image and show it on a label, do:

```
request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo1w.png"))
reply = view.page().networkAccessManager().get(request)
byte_array = reply.readAll()
image = QImage()
image.loadFromData(byte_array)
label = QLabel()
label.setPixmap(QPixmap(image))
label.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to extract the `src` attribute of the `<img/>` HTML tag containing the image and then create the image with the `src` attribute.

```
imgTags = doc.findAll("img")
imgRightTag = QWebElement()

# Find the right <img/> tag and put it in imgRightTag

imgURL = "http://www.google.com" + imgRightTag.attribute("src")
image = QImage(imgURL)
```

Comment: Sorry to be so crap, but copy-pasting your code doesn't seem to work. I tried to interpret it and managed to get a QString from `imgURL = doc.findFirst("img").attribute("src")`, with a value equal to `'/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png'`. But I struggle with the next step... how do I access the image that this string is supposed to point to? QImage().load(imgURL) returns False.

Comment: Prepend the base URL. " http://google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png " should work. I edited my answer for that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the prepended chain either (and I'd rather not download again an image that has just been downloaded).